# Lombok - Hibernate @OneToOne in same class - StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working with 2 tables: Person and City. I have a @ManyToOne relationship which worked fine. (many persons can belong to one city).
Then I needed to create a parent-child relationship. (one person can be parent of another person). The code:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Person parentPerson;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentPerson")
    private Person childPerson;

    public Person() {
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = false)
    private City city;
}


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private Integer cityId;
    
    [...]
}
```

This code compiles, I let hibernate to create the table and I can see the `parent_id` column.
However, after I inserted a few rows and ran `myRepository.findAll()`, I'm getting the following:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:1165)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at package.City.toString(City.java:15)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at package.Person.toString(Person.java:16)
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at package.Person.toString(Person.java:16)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
[...]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at package.Person.toString(Person.java:16)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
```

Even inspecting the result in debug, it was returning the StackOverFlow error, but the child-parent mappings were done correctly. Even though from parent I could inspect/expand the child, then expand the parent and so on...

The example with @OneToOne in the same class is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487070/how-to-add-onetoone-mapping-for-self-entity-in-hibernate).
Any ideas on how I can solve the issue?

Comment: I assume that something is trying to generate toString representation where all properties are stringified which leads to an endless loop of toString from parent to child child to parent parent to child and so on. 

Do you have some post processing after findAll or using lombok? Or does it directly occurs after invoking `repository.findAll()`

Comment: Did you add `@Data` to `Person` or include a custom (possibly auto-generated) `toString`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using lombok. Will try without it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Daniel Wosch and @dan1st for suggestions.
Indeed, the generated toString from Lombok's @Data was the problem.
Solution was to use @Getter, @Setter, @EqualsAndHashCode from Lombok and my own toString which didnt reference both parent and child. Just one of them and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be adding the following annotation right after the Data annotation: @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false,exclude="your relational properties")
Just replace the value of exclude with your field.